# How do I get values from a deep link in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking

I'm implementing deep-linking in android, what I'm trying to do is when a user clicks on the link, he gets redirected on the application, and this already works, but I also want that the user can see some values I pass inside the link.

Example:

My link is: https://examplelink.com/123456789. The application needs to get 123456789 code.

How do I do this?

NB: I've alredy put this on the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sendsharedlink">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="examplelink.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I HAVE RESOLVED BY PUTTING:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();

String[] link = data.toString().split("/");

txt.setText(link[3]);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first copy  this code in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="your host name"
                    android:pathPrefix="your path"
                    android:scheme="https" />


            </intent-filter>
```

This is our app link: https://myapp.page.link/path?email=your@gmail.com&token=12345

and in my splash activity i get data with kotlin code:

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                val data: Uri? = intent?.data
                // get path
                val path = data?.path
                // get param
                val email = data?.getQueryParameter("email").toString()

            }.addOnFailureListener(this) { e -> MLog.e(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure $e") }
```